# Routines in the book Numerical Recipes

Tags: compilation, subroutine, numerical-methods

I need to implement of the routines in the book Numerical Recipes available on http://www.nr.com/. However, due to my inexperience I cannot figure out how to do so. I am puzzled about compilation settings, which files to include, how to modify the main file etc. By the way I am writing in plain C. It would be very nice if you can  point me to a tutorial on this topic. Furthermore, ,in our schools database we have some of these files, yet I suspect they may be outdated as the book has three editions. Therefore I would like to resort to a new resource if possible; are they freely available on internet?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for sources titled "C for Scientists" or "C for engineers". The first google hit contains answers to your questions: (http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/teach/module_home/px270/week2/week_2a.pdf).

---

Have also a look at (http://sccn.ucsd.edu/labinfo/computer-faq/Numerical_Recipes.html), your paths may be different.

Comment: Okay I have done as told, but I am always getting an error messag when I try to compile the file regarding the function definitions in "nr.h" header file.

Comment: Please provide more information on where you got the nr.h file, which version of the book it is from, what tutorial you are following. Give an example of a function definition that causes an error message.

Comment: And the distributed nr.h file is for C++, it contains lines with "namespace NR". Follow the advice on (http://www.nr.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42) about making your own interface files for the specific routines that are used from the library.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have consulted my instructor today but he did not provide much information on them and the version of the book, yet he said that probably it was from the 2nd edition of the book we have the codes on a server by the way. I am sure they are not from the 3rd edition as its header file has the name nr3.h. By the way by looking inside the code how can you identify whether its C or C++, forgive my inexperience ?

Comment: By looking for C++ typical constructs like namespaces, classes, templates.

Comment: Is there any way I can modify them to use in my C programs since I am a bit unfamiliar with C++ at the moment?

Comment: No, you can not modify them without knowing exactly what you do. You are not telling enough details to say what exactly you need to do